# How can I enable SSO strict mode if the issuer and identity provider ID are different?

Tags: python, flask, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am working in a project that I recently inherited to make it production ready. One of the tasks is to enable strict mode for SSO, however once I do this it immediately fails.

I am utilizing the 'python-saml' library to provide the SSO functionality for the application. After some debugging the script is failing here:

```
    # Checks the issuers
    issuers = self.get_issuers()
    for issuer in issuers:
        if issuer is None or issuer != idp_entity_id:
            raise OneLogin_Saml2_ValidationError(
                'Invalid issuer in the Assertion/Response (expected %(idpEntityId)s, got %(issuer)s)' %
                {
                    'idpEntityId': idp_entity_id,
                    'issuer': issuer
                },
                OneLogin_Saml2_ValidationError.WRONG_ISSUER
```

What this tells me is that the issuer is different than the identity provider ID, which it actually is.

My knowledge on SSO is limited, however, it seems strange that this would be different.

How can this be resolved, or how can I enable strict mode if these are different on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the understanding of the idp entity ID value. This should be identical to the Issuer in the SAML response.